# pydev debugging: how to make the debug session automatically stop at the first executable line?

Tags: pydev

Can I make debug sessions in Aptana (with pydev) stop automatically on the first executable line, as if I had set a breakpoint there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not currently. Please open a feature request for that in the PyDev tracker (links: http://pydev.org/about.html)